# How to kill apache spark application running in background after killing it from SPARK web UI

Tags: python, apache-spark, sigkill

Code below is successfully created spark context when I submit using
`spark submit` and running fine.

When I kill application under `Running Applications` from Apache spark
web UI, application state shows `killed` but, printing `Test application` on screen after killing also:

Application running on apache spark web UI:

[image]

Application killed using "kill" button on spark web UI

[image]

Still printing message on screen after killing application

[image]

#### Need solution to auto kill python job when I kill spark-context

```
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark import SparkContext

if __name__ == "__main__":
    conf = SparkConf().setAppName("TEST")
    conf.set("spark.scheduler.mode", "FAIR")
    sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

    while True:
        print("Test application")
```

Comment: Are you running Spark Application over Yarn. If yes then kill it from Yarn using command "Yarn application -kill <application id>"

Comment: Submitting through command editor  **spark-submit test_spark.py** manually and I can see print output on same command editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to solve my issue with below code. Thanks for all your responses

```
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark import SparkContext

if __name__ == "__main__":
    conf = SparkConf().setAppName("TEST")
    conf.set("spark.scheduler.mode", "FAIR")
    sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

    while True:
        if sc._jsc.sc().isStopped():
            break
        print("Test application")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the old fashioned way.

Run ps -ef and find the java job id. Then run kill -9

```
//Find all the java jobs
[stack_overflow@stack_overflow ~]$ ps -ef | grep SparkSubmit
stack_overflow  96747  96736 99 11:19 pts/15   00:01:55 /usr/bin/java -cp /opt/spark/conf/:/opt/spark/jars/* -Dscala.usejavacp=true -Xmx1g -Dderby.system.home=/home/stack_overflow/Spark/ org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit --conf spark.local.dir=/opt/spark/temp_land/spark-temp --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dderby.system.home=/home/stack_overflow/ --class org.apache.spark.repl.Main --name Spark shell spark-shell
stack_overflow  97410  14952  0 11:20 pts/15   00:00:00 grep --color=auto SparkSubmit
//96747 is the Spark job I forced to become unresponsive
//97410 is the Base Spark Account don't delete
////Run the kill command on the job, only works if you have permissions on that job
[stack_overflow@stack_overflow ~]$ kill -9 96747
//The job is now dead and gone
[stack_overflow@stack_overflow ~]$ ps -ef | grep SparkSubmit
stack_overflow  96190  14952  0 11:17 pts/15   00:00:00 grep --color=auto SparkSubmit
```

Comment: Thanks for response. Can I handle in python program? Reason: in production I can be able to submit multiple spark jobs jobs and each job contains separate sparkcontext. I'm expecting if I kill spark context session on spark UI it should kill whole application execution.

Comment: Lets say I spin up 10 Spark Jobs each with their own SparkContext then they should each have their own PID or Job_ID to kill. For your question, no you can kill directly from Spark (everyonce and a while the job goes aberrant) as you have seen and doesn't die. However if you are interested you can set up a watcher to kill on command. 

(1) From a high-level get a program to watch a folder, check every 2 seconds and sleep, (2) When you make your SparkContext give it a unique App_Name, (3) When you want it to be killed use java.file.io to place a file in the folder with the name of App Name.

Comment: The watcher parses the App_Name uses it in the above grep, identified the pid, and kill it. Sorry there really isn't an easy way to kill these jobs dynamically in Spark.

Comment: Thanks for details. Below I posted code it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can open another session and see if your spark application is still running -

```
yarn application -list <app_id>
```

then kill your application if still running,

```
yarn application -kill <app_id>
```

Comment: Ajay thanks for response. I'm not using yarn here exception is to handle programmatically

Comment: I am not sure but you may try using shutdown hook to gracefully shutdown the application. Good Luck.